# How to "Turn On" Version Editor in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, xcode4

How to do so?

What URL is the documentation of version editor?

If I click version editor toolbutton I just see an empty screen to the right

Answer (score 4):

The quasi-answer (workaround) to your question (I think) is that.. there IS NO such thing as a "turn on" for this feature.  If it isn't showing up right - which I've seen *many* times - means Xcode is having a debatably-temporary mental lapse.  *Chances are* - it (Xcode) is about to crash… but if you just want to be done with it / seal the deal / put the horse out of it's misery, etc..

1. quit Xcode.
2. reopen Xcode.

<strike>and you *should* be able to browse your versions</strike>, á la Time Machine, as usual.

***EDIT*** *Ripley's believe it or not* ® I think I'm wrong!

More likely is that your git "arrangement" has become "f-ed up", somehow-or-other.

For me no amount of committing in the GitHub client for Mac would remedy the situation (for *some* files)… However, [thanks to this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525665/547214), i guess forcing Xcode to "take a good, long look at itself in the mirror" via the "actual" Xcode `File -> Source control => commit` command *does* seem to bring back the version-editing functionality of problematic source files.