# Why does Xcode 4 version editor sometimes say "no editor"

Tags: xcode, xcode4, version-editor

In the Project Navigator, there is a little "M" next to the project file, meaning it's been modified.
So I tap the Version Editor.  The left side shows me the contents of the project file, and the right side says "No Editor".  Same thing if I go into Source Control, Commit Selected Files...

However, other files (.m, .h, .plist, etc.) all show real differences, and correctly check-in changes.

Do I have this mis-configured somehow?

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me before I updated to Xcode 4.0.2.  I think it's a bug.  However, try to refresh status by going to `File -> Source Control -> Refresh Status`.

Also, may be obvious, but make sure you actually select the modified file by clicking it in the source tree.

Comment: I think it's a bug too. I am running 4.0.2, I did the refresh status, and my file is definitely selected.  So the mystery remains...

Comment: I've just had this bug in Xcode Version 7.3 beta 3. Hope its fixed in major bundle.

Answer (score 4):

I had this too, exact same problem.

This is despite the fact that you can be using either the organizer interface, or the command line interface, and they appear fine.

Until a file has been updated through the Xcode File...Source Control..commit it doesn't recognize the file, and the version editor will appear to not be working.

Symptom :The Right pane will show messages like File Added and Unversioned File, and the left pane will only ever show the current local Revision.

This is particularly odd because the jump bars and timeline will show the other revisions, you just can't get to them.

The Workaround is to make a small edit to each file then use Xcode's File..Source Control..Commit.

Then the files (and their prior revisions) will start showing up in the version editor.

Comment: Note: just doing a commit without editing the file won't work. Git will ignore commits of files that haven't changed, even though you mark it to commit anyway.

Comment: I have a similar issue with XCode and maybe someone knows the answer: I replaced some files from a library I am using (got a new release). So as XCode does not know the replace file feature (odd enough!) I deleted the files and copied them again into the project. But since then, one file remains in status A (added) and XCode simply won't regocnize that GIT already added it to version control. Any hints? Cheers, René

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem as well using an SVN repository.  It was resolved once I went into the organizer and verified that I could see the revision history of the branch I was working on.  I had to hit refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after stashing , changing branch and then unstashing using git/sourcetree.

None of the above worked, but deleting the workspace did.
As per this link.
[Xcode 4 - slow performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355667/xcode-4-slow-performance)

The was on Xcode 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with XCode 4.4.1

My Solution:
While he showed No Editor on the Version Control View, the top bar was saying "Loading Revision" and had a infinite progression bar.
I just double clicked the progression bar and the files were loaded on the editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up a local git to act as a source control, This will make your file>Source Control>Commit work.

I think this will go some way to answering your particular problem.

Warning, to pull previous versions you need to come out of XCode (for safety) and use the CLI git.

See this for excellent help on this topic.

[Xcode 4 git integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302367/xcode-4-git-integration)

Answer (score 0):

(subversion SCM)
Doing an update action in the organizer Repositories pane does resync Xcode and sort out the problem. No need to commit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this "No Editor" problem when I tried to duplicate a project to do some experimentation on by simply selecting the folder and selecting File>Duplicate in the Finder. Xcode didn't like this, and not only did the duplicated project give a "No Editor" problem, but (after erasing the duplicated project) I found that the original project gave a "No Editor" problem whenever I tried to open it.

My solution was to simply use Time Capsule to restore the project folder to before I caused all of these problems. It worked!

I'm still a bit puzzled about why it worked, though, because the Finder indicated that none of the original project files had been modified as a result of anything I had done. Perhaps there were some invisible files or something that had been changed....

Answer (score 0):

No idea, but for me, I could get back into my project by choosing it from recent files

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Xcode 7.2.1. I did a 'Product-Clean' and then chose 'Source Control-History' and one of the historic commits by selecting "Show # modified files" AND THEN chose the list icon in the upper left part of window (after the page icon). Now all works fine.